# Set readonly dynamically in tagify

Tags: javascript, jquery, tagify

I am trying to dynamically set the input field tied to tagify as readonly. According to [tagify's documentation](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify#methods) I thought I should be able to simply do this:

```
tagify.setReadonly(true);
```

I am seeing an error message though:

> tagify.setReadonly is not a function

Tagify is initiated like this:

```
var tagify = new Tagify(document.getElementById("Tags"), { whitelist: [] })
```

I tried other settings, e.g. `removeAllTags` and they seem to be working fine this fine. Any idea what I could be doing wrong? Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: Something in your code may have inadverently overwritten the property. What does `console.log(tagify.setReadonly)` show?

Comment: That error means "The property setReadonly exists, but it contains something other than a function".

Comment: @Barmar, running `Console.log(tagify.setReadonly)` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Apparently I was wrong, the same error message is used when the property doesn't exist.

Comment: What about `Tagify.prototype.setReadonly`?

Comment: @Barmer: This returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setReadonly' of undefined`

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. It's clearly assigned: https://github.com/yairEO/tagify/blob/master/src/tagify.js#L55

Comment: It leaves me puzzled as well...

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. Something in your application is messing with `Tagify`.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, will do! I appreciate all your help :-)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
tagify.setReadonly('set', 'readonly');
```

You can find it in tagify documentation also.
https://github.com/yairEO/tagify/blob/master/src/tagify.js#L979